# Retrieving file and folder inside VM remotely using other system

Tags: centos, centos7, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, data-recovery

Recently my teammate accidentally deletes numerous files even important system files inside development server. because of this our staff cannot login even in local so we cannot recover remaining files.

so we plan to try to bring out all remaining files inside /home and /var using other system (another server). its solved if its physical mount, but **how we access this folder if this server is not phsyical server?** (this is VM, we're using Centos KVM).

sory my bad english,

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect to the VM over the network from another machine besides the host system, the VM's networking will need to be configured in such a manner so it can access the main network. That is called "bridged mode". That will give that VM an IP address from the main network pool.

Check the NIC device on the "virtual hardware details" screen and verify that the network mode is set to "bridged".